# Access deep object member of embeded JSON

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, ecmascript-5

The following function does an amazing job of retrieving a deep object key value with a dot notated string:

```
function getPathValue(obj, path) {
  return new Function('_', 'return _.' + path)(obj);
}
```

For example, it returns the value for a key like "bar" using the following as the path argument:

```
'data.abc.foo.bar'
```

However, some API's pack additional stringified JSON into some key values.

I'm looking for an enhancement to the above function that will handle that case.

For example, Stack's own WebSocket service:

```
wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/
```

returns strings like this:

```
{"action":"155-questions-active","data":"{\"siteBaseHostAddress\":\"stackoverflow.com\",\"id\":53819390,\"titleEncodedFancy\":\"Should I start with webGL1 or webGL2 when using Three.js\",\"bodySummary\":\"Spent some time learning and understanding the basics of webGL and I'm now diving into Three.js.\\n\\nI noticed that I have the option of using webGL1 or webGL2. Seems as if webGL1 is the default, however ...\",\"tags\":[\"three.js\",\"webgl\"],\"lastActivityDate\":1545064508,\"url\":\"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819390/should-i-start-with-webgl1-or-webgl2-when-using-three-js\",\"ownerUrl\":\"https://stackoverflow.com/users/8226111/romanrogers\",\"ownerDisplayName\":\"romanrogers\",\"apiSiteParameter\":\"stackoverflow\"}"}
```

And I'd like to be able to use the above function to retrieve values with an input string like:

```
'data.bodySummary'
```

Perhaps the input string could look something like:

```
'data/bodySummary'
```

where the solidus (/slash) represents a JSON.parse().

Note, this needs to be dynamic as I'd like to make it where the end user can select arbitrary keys to return values for in the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the item from where you take a property is a string an perform a parsing. The return the value of the property.

```js
function getValue(object, path) {
    return path
        .split('.')
        .reduce((o, k) => (typeof o === 'string' ? JSON.parse(o) : o)[k], object);
}

var data = {"action":"155-questions-active","data":"{\"siteBaseHostAddress\":\"stackoverflow.com\",\"id\":53819390,\"titleEncodedFancy\":\"Should I start with webGL1 or webGL2 when using Three.js\",\"bodySummary\":\"Spent some time learning and understanding the basics of webGL and I'm now diving into Three.js.\\n\\nI noticed that I have the option of using webGL1 or webGL2. Seems as if webGL1 is the default, however ...\",\"tags\":[\"three.js\",\"webgl\"],\"lastActivityDate\":1545064508,\"url\":\"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819390/should-i-start-with-webgl1-or-webgl2-when-using-three-js\",\"ownerUrl\":\"https://stackoverflow.com/users/8226111/romanrogers\",\"ownerDisplayName\":\"romanrogers\",\"apiSiteParameter\":\"stackoverflow\"}"};

console.log(getValue(data, 'data.bodySummary'));
```

ES5

```js
function getValue(object, path) {
    return path
        .split('.')
        .reduce(function (o, k) {
            return (typeof o === 'string' ? JSON.parse(o) : o)[k];
        }, object);
}

var data = {"action":"155-questions-active","data":"{\"siteBaseHostAddress\":\"stackoverflow.com\",\"id\":53819390,\"titleEncodedFancy\":\"Should I start with webGL1 or webGL2 when using Three.js\",\"bodySummary\":\"Spent some time learning and understanding the basics of webGL and I'm now diving into Three.js.\\n\\nI noticed that I have the option of using webGL1 or webGL2. Seems as if webGL1 is the default, however ...\",\"tags\":[\"three.js\",\"webgl\"],\"lastActivityDate\":1545064508,\"url\":\"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819390/should-i-start-with-webgl1-or-webgl2-when-using-three-js\",\"ownerUrl\":\"https://stackoverflow.com/users/8226111/romanrogers\",\"ownerDisplayName\":\"romanrogers\",\"apiSiteParameter\":\"stackoverflow\"}"};

console.log(getValue(data, 'data.bodySummary'));
```

Comment: I like this a lot. But my requirement is IE11 and ES5. Can you rework that without the arrow function?

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.

Comment: Is there a way to enhance this so that it works when the JSON has arrays in it and the path includes one or more? Let me know and I can start a new question if you like.

Comment: it would be better to ask a new question with an example of the data, you have and a mored detailed view, what you want, as it is possible to discuss in the comment section.

Comment: I just posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53841772/3566998

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that takes an object or a JSON string as it's first param, a key path string or array as it's second param, and recursively walks the object with the key path.

```js
let object = {"action":"155-questions-active","data":"{\"siteBaseHostAddress\":\"stackoverflow.com\",\"id\":53819390,\"titleEncodedFancy\":\"Should I start with webGL1 or webGL2 when using Three.js\",\"bodySummary\":\"Spent some time learning and understanding the basics of webGL and I'm now diving into Three.js.\\n\\nI noticed that I have the option of using webGL1 or webGL2. Seems as if webGL1 is the default, however ...\",\"tags\":[\"three.js\",\"webgl\"],\"lastActivityDate\":1545064508,\"url\":\"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819390/should-i-start-with-webgl1-or-webgl2-when-using-three-js\",\"ownerUrl\":\"https://stackoverflow.com/users/8226111/romanrogers\",\"ownerDisplayName\":\"romanrogers\",\"apiSiteParameter\":\"stackoverflow\"}"};

function asObject(str) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return str;
    }
}


function valueAtKeyPath(o, path) {
    o = asObject(o);
    if (typeof path === 'string') path = path.split('.');
    
    if (!o || !path.length) return o;
    return valueAtKeyPath(o[path[0]], path.slice(1));
}

console.log(valueAtKeyPath(object, 'action'))
console.log(valueAtKeyPath(object, 'data.id'))
```

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't return string values for paths like:

valueAtKeyPath(object, 'action')

Comment: @ExcelHero - I see what you mean.  Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for this. It works. I appreciate you updating it as well. I'm selecting Nina's because it was first and I like how conicse it is. I also like that it returns the string instead of the object for the path:  'data'