# getPathValue() function for deep objects with arrays and with packed JSON

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, ecmascript-5

For background, please refer to this question:
[Access deep object member of embeded JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53819904/3566998)

The solutions offered there worked very well with the packed JSON contained in key values.

However, they don't handle the situation where JSON has arrays.

The original function I referenced in the other question DID handle arrays, but it would not handle the packed JSON.

This is the original function:

```
function getPathValue(obj, path) {
    return new Function('_', 'return _.' + path)(obj);
}
```

and this is the answer from the first question:

```
function getValue(object, path) {
    return path
        .split('.')
        .reduce((o, k) => (typeof o === 'string' ? JSON.parse(o) : o)[k], 
object);
}
```

Again, both work well, but neither offers the whole package.

I need a solution that will do both and it must work in IE11's ES5.

Here is a sample API returned JSON string:

```
{"id":"0001","type":"donut","name":"Cake","ppu":0.55,"batters":{"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"},{"id":"1002","type":"Chocolate"}]},"data":"{\"domain\":\"cooking.com\",\"id\":53819390}"}
```

I'd like to be able to query values with a path string, for example:

```
value = getPathValue(obj, 'batters.batter[2].id');
```

or

```
value = getPathValue(obj, 'type');
```

or

```
value = getPathValue(obj, 'data.domain');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the brackets and take the remaining values as keys. Inside of the reducing, you could use a default object for not given objects.

```js
function getValue(object, path) {
    return path
        .replace(/\[/g, '.')
        .replace(/\]/g, '')
        .split('.')
        .reduce(function (o, k) {
            return (typeof o === 'string' ? JSON.parse(o) : (o || {}))[k];
        }, object);
}
var object = {"id":"0001","type":"donut","name":"Cake","ppu":0.55,"batters":{"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"},{"id":"1002","type":"Chocolate"}]},"data":"{\"domain\":\"cooking.com\",\"id\":53819390}"},
    path = 'batters.batter[1].id';

console.log(getValue(object, path));
```

Comment: I just added another follow up question:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/53963970/3566998

Answer (score 0):

The following would do the job using a Regex on each value :

```js
const data = {
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters": {
        "batter": [
            {
                "id": "1001",
                "type": "Regular"
            },
            {
                "id": "1002",
                "type": "Chocolate"
            }
        ]
    },
    "data": "{\"domain\":\"cooking.com\",\"id\":53819390}"
}

function getValue(object, path) {
    return path
        .split('.')
        .reduce(function (o, k) {
            const indexSearch = (new RegExp(/\[([0-9]*)\]/)).exec(k)
            const index = indexSearch ? indexSearch[1] : null
            k = k.replace(/\[[0-9]*\]/, '')
            const sub = (typeof o === 'string' ? JSON.parse(o) : o)[k]
            return index ? sub[index] : sub;
        }, object);
}

console.log(getValue(data, 'batters.batter[1]'))
console.log(getValue(data, 'data.domain'))
console.log(getValue(data, 'batters.batter[1].id'))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I appreciate it. However, I really like the conciseness of Nina's solution.